# Not able to process particular number of lines with Spark Streaming

Tags: streaming, apache-spark, logistic-regression

I am using Spark-1.0.0 over a 3 node cluster with 1 master and 2 slaves. I am trying to run LR algorithm over Spark Streaming.

```
package org.apache.spark.examples.streaming;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;

/**
 * Logistic regression based classification using ML Lib.
 */
public final class StreamingJavaLR {
    static int i = 1;

    // static LogisticRegressionModel model;

    // private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

    static class ParsePoint implements Function<String, LabeledPoint> {
        private static final Pattern COMMA = Pattern.compile(",");
        private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

        @Override
        public LabeledPoint call(String line) {
            String[] parts = COMMA.split(line);
            double y = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
            String[] tok = SPACE.split(parts[1]);
            double[] x = new double[tok.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < tok.length; ++i) {
                x[i] = Double.parseDouble(tok[i]);
            }
            return new LabeledPoint(y, Vectors.dense(x));
        }
    }

    // Edited
    static class ParsePointforInput implements Function<String, double[]> {
        private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

        @Override
        public double[] call(String line) {
            String[] tok = SPACE.split(line);
            double[] x = new double[tok.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < tok.length; ++i) {
                x[i] = Double.parseDouble(tok[i]);
            }
            return x;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length != 5) {
            System.err
                    .println("Usage: JavaLR <master> <input_file_for_training> <step_size> <no_iters> <input_file_for_prediction>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        FileWriter file;
        PrintWriter outputFile = null;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();

        final Date startTime;

        System.out.println("<<<<<Let's Print>>>>>");

//      SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
//                .setMaster(args[0])
//              .setAppName("StreamingJavaLR")
//                .set("spark.cleaner.ttl", "1000")
//                .set("spark.executor.uri", "hdfs://192.168.145.191:9000/user/praveshj/spark/spark-0.9.1.tar.gz")
//              .setJars(JavaSparkContext.jarOfClass(StreamingJavaLR.class));
//
//      JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

         JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(args[0],
         "StreamingJavaLR",
         System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"),
         JavaSparkContext.jarOfClass(StreamingJavaLR.class));

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Reading File");
        JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile(args[1]);
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>File has been Read now mapping");
        JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> points = lines.map(new ParsePoint()).cache();
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Mapping Done");
        double stepSize = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
        int iterations = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Read the arguments. stepSize = "+stepSize+" and iterations = "+iterations);

        BufferedReader br = null;

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Training the Model");
        final LogisticRegressionModel model = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(
                points.rdd(), iterations, stepSize);
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Model Trained");

        System.out.println("Final w: " + model.weights());
        //      printWeights(model.weights());
        System.out.println("Intercept : " + model.intercept());

        final Vector weightVector = model.weights();

//      double[] weightArray = model.weights();
//
//      final DoubleMatrix weightMatrix = new DoubleMatrix(weightArray);

        sc.stop();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

//      try {
//          file = new FileWriter(args[5]);
//          outputFile = new PrintWriter(file);
//          cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//          cal.getTime();
////            startTime = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
//          startTime = cal.getTime();
//          outputFile.println("Start Time : " + startTime);
//          outputFile.flush();
//      } catch (IOException E) {
//          E.printStackTrace();
//      }

//      final JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc,
//              new Duration(1000));

        startTime = cal.getTime();

        final JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(args[0],
        "StreamingJavaLR", new Duration(1000),
        System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"),
        JavaStreamingContext.jarOfClass(StreamingJavaLR.class));

        JavaDStream<String> lines_2 = ssc.textFileStream(args[4]);
        JavaDStream<double[]> points_2 = lines_2.map(new ParsePointforInput());
        // points_2.print();


        // System.out.print(lines_2.count());
        // System.exit(0);
        points_2.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<double[]>, Void>() {

            @Override
            public Void call(JavaRDD rdd) {

                List<double[]> temp = rdd.collect();

                //If no more data is left for Prediction, Stop the Program
//              if (rdd.count() == 0)
//                  ssc.stop();
                FileWriter newfile = null;
                BufferedWriter bw = null;

                try {
                    newfile = new FileWriter(
                            "/home/pravesh/data/abc"
                                    + i++ + ".txt");
                    bw = new BufferedWriter(newfile);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int inpNo = 0;
                double result;
                for (double[] dArray : temp) {
                    double[][] dataArray = new double[1][2];
                    for (int i = 0; i < dArray.length; i++)
                        dataArray[0][i] = dArray[i];
//                  DoubleMatrix dataMatrix = new DoubleMatrix(dataArray);
//                  result = model.predictPoint(dataMatrix, weightMatrix,
//                          model.intercept());

                    Vector dataVector = Vectors.dense(dArray);
                    result = model.predictPoint(dataVector, weightVector, model.intercept());

                    try {                       
                        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
//                      bw.write("INFO at " + cal2.getTime() + " : " + "Point " + inpNo + " (" + dataMatrix.get(0, 0)
//                              + ", " + dataMatrix.get(0, 1) + ")"
//                              + " belongs to : " + result + " and Start Time was " + startTime + "\n");

                        bw.write("INFO at " + cal2.getTime() + " : " + "Point " + inpNo + " (" + dataVector.toArray()[0]
                                + ", " + dataVector.toArray()[1] + ")"
                                + " belongs to : " + result + " and Start Time was " + startTime + "\n");

                        bw.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // newoutputFile.flush();
                    inpNo++;
                }
                try {
                    bw.close();
                    newfile.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Void v = null;
                return v;
            }
        });

        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();

//      cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//      outputFile.println("  End Time : " + cal.getTime());
//      outputFile.flush();

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I take input from files for training the model with JavaSparkContext and for testing the model with JavaStreamingContext.

I have used the data given in $SPARK_HOME/mllib/data/lr-data/random.data for training and testing. To obtain larger data sets, I have copied this data. The code works fine for every possible set of data in local mode. Over the cluster, however, it is not able to process the file containing 0.4million entries.

For every other data set (file with 0.8 million entries here), the output is like (Output after the StreamingContext is started):

```
14/06/06 11:36:09 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20140606113609-0001/0 on hostPort host-DSRV05.host.co.in:55206 with 8 cores, 512.0 MB RAM
14/06/06 11:36:09 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20140606113609-0001/1 on worker-20140606114445-host-DSRV04.host.co.in-39342 (host-DSRV04.host.co.in:39342) with 8 cores
14/06/06 11:36:09 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20140606113609-0001/1 on hostPort host-DSRV04.host.co.in:39342 with 8 cores, 512.0 MB RAM
14/06/06 11:36:09 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606113609-0001/0 is now RUNNING
14/06/06 11:36:09 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606113609-0001/1 is now RUNNING
14/06/06 11:36:09 INFO RecurringTimer: Started timer for JobGenerator at time 1402034770000
14/06/06 11:36:09 INFO JobGenerator: Started JobGenerator at 1402034770000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:09 INFO JobScheduler: Started JobScheduler
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 29 ms
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034770000 ms:
file:/newdisk1/praveshj/pravesh/data/input/testing8lk.txt
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(33216) called with curMem=0, maxMem=309225062
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values to memory (estimated size 32.4 KB, free 294.9 MB)
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034770000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1402034770000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034770000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170) with 1 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 0(collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170)
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 0 (MappedRDD[3] at map at MappedDStream.scala:35), which has no missing parents
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from Stage 0 (MappedRDD[3] at map at MappedDStream.scala:35)
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor: Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@host-DSRV05.host.co.in:47657/user/Executor#-1277914179] with ID 0
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0:0 as TID 0 on executor 0: host-DSRV05.host.co.in (PROCESS_LOCAL)
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Serialized task 0.0:0 as 3544 bytes in 1 ms
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor: Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@host-DSRV04.host.co.in:46975/user/Executor#1659982546] with ID 1
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Registering block manager host-DSRV05.host.co.in:52786 with 294.9 MB RAM
14/06/06 11:36:10 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Registering block manager host-DSRV04.host.co.in:42008 with 294.9 MB RAM
14/06/06 11:36:11 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 0 ms
14/06/06 11:36:11 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034771000 ms:

14/06/06 11:36:11 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034771000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:12 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 1 ms
14/06/06 11:36:12 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034772000 ms:

14/06/06 11:36:12 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034772000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:13 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 0 ms
14/06/06 11:36:13 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034773000 ms:

14/06/06 11:36:13 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034773000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:14 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 0 ms
14/06/06 11:36:14 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034774000 ms:

14/06/06 11:36:14 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034774000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:15 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 0 ms
14/06/06 11:36:15 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034775000 ms:

14/06/06 11:36:15 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034775000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:15 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added taskresult_0 in memory on host-DSRV05.host.co.in:52786 (size: 19.9 MB, free: 275.0 MB)
14/06/06 11:36:15 INFO SendingConnection: Initiating connection to [host-DSRV05.host.co.in/192.168.145.195:52786]
14/06/06 11:36:15 INFO SendingConnection: Connected to [host-DSRV05.host.co.in/192.168.145.195:52786], 1 messages pending
14/06/06 11:36:15 INFO ConnectionManager: Accepted connection from [host-DSRV05.host.co.in/192.168.145.195]
14/06/06 11:36:15 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed taskresult_0 on host-DSRV05.host.co.in:52786 in memory (size: 19.9 MB, free: 294.9 MB)
14/06/06 11:36:15 INFO DAGScheduler: Completed ResultTask(0, 0)
14/06/06 11:36:15 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished TID 0 in 4961 ms on host-DSRV05.host.co.in (progress: 1/1)
14/06/06 11:36:15 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
14/06/06 11:36:15 INFO DAGScheduler: Stage 0 (collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170) finished in 5.533 s
14/06/06 11:36:15 INFO SparkContext: Job finished: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170, took 5.548644244 s
14/06/06 11:36:16 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 1 ms
14/06/06 11:36:16 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034776000 ms:

14/06/06 11:36:16 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034776000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:17 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 0 ms
14/06/06 11:36:17 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034777000 ms:

14/06/06 11:36:17 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034777000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:18 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 0 ms
14/06/06 11:36:18 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034778000 ms:

14/06/06 11:36:18 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034778000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 0 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034779000 ms:

14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034779000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1402034770000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034770000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 9.331 s for time 1402034770000 ms (execution: 9.274 s)
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Job finished: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170, took 2.7293E-5 s
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1402034771000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034771000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1402034771000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034771000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 8.333 s for time 1402034771000 ms (execution: 0.000 s)
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1402034772000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034772000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Job finished: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170, took 1.4859E-5 s
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1402034772000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034772000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 7.335 s for time 1402034772000 ms (execution: 0.002 s)
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1402034773000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034773000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Job finished: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170, took 1.5294E-5 s
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1402034773000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034773000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 6.336 s for time 1402034773000 ms (execution: 0.001 s)
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1402034774000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034774000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Job finished: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170, took 1.117E-5 s
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1402034774000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034774000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 5.337 s for time 1402034774000 ms (execution: 0.001 s)
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1402034775000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034775000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO FileInputDStream: Cleared 0 old files that were older than 1402034769000 ms: 
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Job finished: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170, took 1.1414E-5 s
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1402034775000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034775000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 4.338 s for time 1402034775000 ms (execution: 0.001 s)
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1402034776000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034776000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Job finished: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170, took 4.2422E-5 s
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1402034776000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034776000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 3.338 s for time 1402034776000 ms (execution: 0.000 s)
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1402034777000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034777000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO MappedRDD: Removing RDD 3 from persistence list
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Job finished: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170, took 1.1133E-5 s
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1402034777000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034777000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 2.339 s for time 1402034777000 ms (execution: 0.000 s)
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1402034778000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034778000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Job finished: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170, took 1.124E-5 s
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1402034778000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034778000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 1.340 s for time 1402034778000 ms (execution: 0.001 s)
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1402034779000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034779000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO SparkContext: Job finished: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170, took 1.2101E-5 s
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1402034779000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034779000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.341 s for time 1402034779000 ms (execution: 0.001 s)
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 3
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO MappedRDD: Removing RDD 2 from persistence list
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 2
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO UnionRDD: Removing RDD 1 from persistence list
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 1
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO FileInputDStream: Cleared 0 old files that were older than 1402034770000 ms: 
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO MappedRDD: Removing RDD 6 from persistence list
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 6
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO MappedRDD: Removing RDD 5 from persistence list
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 5
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO UnionRDD: Removing RDD 4 from persistence list
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 4
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO FileInputDStream: Cleared 1 old files that were older than 1402034771000 ms: 1402034770000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO MappedRDD: Removing RDD 9 from persistence list
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 9
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO MappedRDD: Removing RDD 8 from persistence list
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 8
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO UnionRDD: Removing RDD 7 from persistence list
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 7
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO FileInputDStream: Cleared 1 old files that were older than 1402034772000 ms: 1402034771000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO MappedRDD: Removing RDD 12 from persistence list
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 12
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO MappedRDD: Removing RDD 11 from persistence list
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 11
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO UnionRDD: Removing RDD 10 from persistence list
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 10
14/06/06 11:36:19 INFO FileInputDStream: Cleared 1 old files that were older than 1402034773000 ms: 1402034772000 ms
14/06/06 11:36:20 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1402034780000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034780000 ms
```

For file with 0.4 million entries, the ouput is (Output after StreamingContext is started) :

```
14/06/06 11:38:55 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20140606113855-0003/0 on worker-20140606114445-host-DSRV05.host.co.in-55206 (host-DSRV05.host.co.in:55206) with 8 cores
14/06/06 11:38:55 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20140606113855-0003/0 on hostPort host-DSRV05.host.co.in:55206 with 8 cores, 512.0 MB RAM
14/06/06 11:38:55 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20140606113855-0003/1 on worker-20140606114445-host-DSRV04.host.co.in-39342 (host-DSRV04.host.co.in:39342) with 8 cores
14/06/06 11:38:55 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20140606113855-0003/1 on hostPort host-DSRV04.host.co.in:39342 with 8 cores, 512.0 MB RAM
14/06/06 11:38:55 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606113855-0003/0 is now RUNNING
14/06/06 11:38:55 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606113855-0003/1 is now RUNNING
14/06/06 11:38:55 INFO RecurringTimer: Started timer for JobGenerator at time 1402034936000
14/06/06 11:38:55 INFO JobGenerator: Started JobGenerator at 1402034936000 ms
14/06/06 11:38:55 INFO JobScheduler: Started JobScheduler
14/06/06 11:38:56 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 31 ms
14/06/06 11:38:56 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034936000 ms:
file:/newdisk1/praveshj/pravesh/data/input/testing4lk.txt
14/06/06 11:38:56 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(33216) called with curMem=0, maxMem=309225062
14/06/06 11:38:56 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values to memory (estimated size 32.4 KB, free 294.9 MB)
14/06/06 11:38:56 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/06/06 11:38:56 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034936000 ms
14/06/06 11:38:56 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1402034936000 ms.0 from job set of time 1402034936000 ms
14/06/06 11:38:56 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170
14/06/06 11:38:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170) with 1 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
14/06/06 11:38:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 0(collect at StreamingJavaLR.java:170)
14/06/06 11:38:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
14/06/06 11:38:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
14/06/06 11:38:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 0 (MappedRDD[3] at map at MappedDStream.scala:35), which has no missing parents
14/06/06 11:38:56 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from Stage 0 (MappedRDD[3] at map at MappedDStream.scala:35)
14/06/06 11:38:56 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
14/06/06 11:38:57 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 1 ms
14/06/06 11:38:57 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034937000 ms:

14/06/06 11:38:57 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034937000 ms
14/06/06 11:38:57 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor: Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@host-DSRV05.host.co.in:39424/user/Executor#-500165450] with ID 0
14/06/06 11:38:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0:0 as TID 0 on executor 0: host-DSRV05.host.co.in (PROCESS_LOCAL)
14/06/06 11:38:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Serialized task 0.0:0 as 3544 bytes in 0 ms
14/06/06 11:38:57 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor: Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@host-DSRV04.host.co.in:45532/user/Executor#1654371091] with ID 1
14/06/06 11:38:57 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Registering block manager host-DSRV05.host.co.in:53857 with 294.9 MB RAM
14/06/06 11:38:57 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Registering block manager host-DSRV04.host.co.in:38057 with 294.9 MB RAM
14/06/06 11:38:58 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 0 ms
14/06/06 11:38:58 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034938000 ms:

14/06/06 11:38:58 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034938000 ms
14/06/06 11:38:59 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 1 ms
14/06/06 11:38:59 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034939000 ms:

14/06/06 11:38:59 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034939000 ms
14/06/06 11:39:00 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 0 ms
14/06/06 11:39:00 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034940000 ms:

14/06/06 11:39:00 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034940000 ms
14/06/06 11:39:01 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 0 ms
14/06/06 11:39:01 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034941000 ms:

14/06/06 11:39:01 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034941000 ms
14/06/06 11:39:02 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 0 ms
14/06/06 11:39:02 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034942000 ms:

14/06/06 11:39:02 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034942000 ms
14/06/06 11:39:03 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 0 ms
14/06/06 11:39:03 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034943000 ms:

14/06/06 11:39:03 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034943000 ms
14/06/06 11:39:04 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 0 ms
14/06/06 11:39:04 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034944000 ms:

14/06/06 11:39:04 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034944000 ms
14/06/06 11:39:05 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 1 ms
14/06/06 11:39:05 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034945000 ms:

14/06/06 11:39:05 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1402034945000 ms
14/06/06 11:39:06 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 1 ms
14/06/06 11:39:06 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1402034946000 ms:
```

and this goes on forever. It doesn't print the output in the file it is supposed to.
The worker logs don't output anything different.

Any idea what might be the issue?

--

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well i was able to get it to work by running spark over mesos. But it looks like a bug while running spark alone.